# Select parent rows where child a is 1 and child b is 2 (mysql)

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I need to select all parent rows where child A matches condition 1 and child B matches condition 2, etc.

The tables are set up one-to-many, where the parent table's primary key is referenced in a column in the the child rows in another table.

```
Parent Table `Pets`
ID | Name
---|-------
1  | Puppy
2  | Cat
3  | Fish

Child Table `PetsProperties`
PetsID    | Property
----------|-------
1         | Furry
1         | Pet
2         | Furry
2         | Pet
3         | Pet
3         | Scaly
```

Given the above tables, if condition 1 is Property = 'Furry' and condition 2 is Property = 'Pet', the query would return:

```
1  | Puppy
2  | Cat
```

But not

```
3  | Fish
```

The query provided by Fabien Werniez works beautifully, and when applied to this test case becomes:

```
SELECT A.* FROM Pets A
INNER JOIN PetsProperties B ON B.PetsID = A.ID AND B.Property= 'Furry'
INNER JOIN PetsProperties C ON C.PetsID = A.ID AND C.Property= 'Pet'
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is not nearly descriptive enough.

Comment: I have reworded the question, is that better? (Please undo your down vote if it is acceptable, although in my defense Fabien Warniez had no trouble answering my question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 INNER JOIN with the conditions added to the ON clause should do it:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.b_id AND B.whatever = condition1
INNER JOIN C ON C.id = A.c_id AND C.whatever = condition2
```